# How can multiple trailing slashes can be removed from a URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, malformed, url-parsing

What I'm trying to achieve here is lets say we have two example URLs:

```
url1 = "http://emy.dod.com/kaskaa/dkaiad/amaa//////////"
url2 = "http://www.example.com/"
```

How can I extract the striped down URLs?

```
url1 = "http://emy.dod.com/kaskaa/dkaiad/amaa"
url2 = "http://http://www.example.com"
```

`URI.parse` in Ruby sanitizes certain type of malformed URL but is ineffective in this case.

If we use regex then `/^(.*)\/$/` removes a single slash `/` from `url1` and is ineffective for `url2`.

Is anybody aware of how to handle this type of URL parsing?

The point here is I don't want my system to have `http://www.example.com/` and `http://www.example.com` being treated as two different URLs. And same goes for `http://emy.dod.com/kaskaa/dkaiad/amaa////` and `http://emy.dod.com/kaskaa/dkaiad/amaa/`.

Comment: @other_people_reading_this_question If, like me, you only need to remove one trailing slash, you can use `String#chomp`. E.g: `"/path/to/directory/".chomp("/")`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just need to remove all slashes from the end of the url string then you can try the following regex:

```
"http://emy.dod.com/kaskaa/dkaiad/amaa//////////".sub(/(\/)+$/,'')
"http://www.example.com/".sub(/(\/)+$/,'')
```

`/(\/)+$/` - this regex finds one or more slashes at the end of the string. Then we replace this match with empty string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer. A minor regex comment is that the parentheses are not required here.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I figured out yesterday gsub(/\/*$/) works too as crudson mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Although this thread is a bit old and the top answer is quite good, but I suggest another way to do this:

```
/^(.*?)\/$/
```

You could see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/vC6yX1/2

The magic here is `*?`, which does a lazy match. So the entire expression could be translated as:

Match as few characters as it can and capture it, while match as many slashes as it can at the end.

Which means, in a more plain English, removes all trailing slashes.

Comment: upvote for being a pure regex, instead of using language-specific functions

Comment: thanks for voting for so long @theEpsilon :D i think this request could be done using only regex, instead of some language specific features.

Answer (score 0):

```
def without_trailing_slash path
  path[ %r(.*[^/]) ]
end

path = "http://emy.dod.com/kaskaa/dkaiad/amaa//////////"

puts without_trailing_slash path # "http://emy.dod.com/kaskaa/dkaiad/amaa"
```