# Remove trailing slash from list of urls with regex

Tags: regex

I have a list of urls

Some have traling slashes

some do not have traling slashes

I need to remove all trailing slashes IF they exist
urls look like this:

https://123.com/@boakye2015/

https://123.com/@boakye2015

please supply the regex to find and replace

Comment: No, need of using regex, you can use `string` functions. Which language you are using?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765483/how-can-multiple-trailing-slashes-can-be-removed-from-a-url-in-ruby

Comment: I am not using any, I am using textpad.

Comment: Still need an answer.

Comment: If you scroll up 2 centimeters you see I commented, that *no* language is used.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sT0sA1/1

Answer (score 0):

[Give this a try](https://regex101.com/r/iZ7cI6/2) and replace with: `\1\2`

```
(http\S+)\/(\s|$)
```

`(...)` first group captures to `\1`, second to `\2`

`\S` matches character that is not whitespace, `\s` whitespace, `$` the end.